# Reading from a plist and then saving objects to a different plist iOS

Tags: ios6, nsarray, plist

After searching around, I have found a large number of posts about bits and pieces of what I want to do, but nothing that works all together.

Bassically I have a static plist file. I DO NOT want to change its contents. The plist file is an array of dictionaries that are read from the plist and stored in a NSArray and the data is displayed on a table. This is the fully working and easy part!

What I want to do now, is have a plist that stores user favorites of the objects read from the static plist array into a NSMutableArray of favorites. This array will need to be read into a favorites table viewed anytime the user selects the favorites section

The concept is simple really, the user will press an "add to favorites button" and the dictionary object will be added to the favorites array, but my problem is properly checking if the favorites plist exists. If it does, read that data into the favorites array. If is does not exist, then create the empty plist, which will still read into the favorites array but it will be empty.

I am not sure where to start for this particular situation, any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this myself, while trying to do the same thing for the first time. The main issue is that you can't write to plist that doesn't exist. So you need to make one in your bundle, and copy it to the location you need it to be, "if it doesn't exist". Here's an example. It's a bit more than "minimal", but I think it explains the issues. The result is something that carries over from one run to another, by storing something in "data.plist" somewhere buried in the documents directory.

In `ViewController.m` (for example):

```c
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

////////////////////////////
// BIG NOTE:
// In order for ANY of this to work, you need to make a data.plist in your supporting files, in your project,
// before compiling and running
// The plist should, at very least, have a single row with key "key1" and value "value1"
////////////////////////////

// returns path where plist file is
// "internal" means whether we want from one baked into the app (which is read-only, by the way), or one in our documents dir
-(NSString *)localPathForPlist:(NSString *)name internal:(bool)internal
{
    if( internal ) return [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory
               // this just adds name and ".plist" to make a filename something like "data.plist"
               stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", name, @".plist"]
           ];
}

// write value to key, either in internal plist or not
-(void) writeToPlist:(NSString *)key setValue:(NSString *)value internal:(bool)internal
{
    NSString* path = [ self localPathForPlist:@"data" internal:internal ];
    NSMutableDictionary *plistData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [plistData setObject:value forKey:key];
    [plistData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}

// read value from key, either in internal plist or not
-(NSString *) readFromPlist:(NSString *)key internal:(bool)internal
{
    NSString* path = [ self localPathForPlist:@"data" internal:internal ];
    NSMutableDictionary *plistData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    return (NSString *)[plistData valueForKey:key];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // here we go through all the different cases, trying to edit things internally and in externally,
    // and copying the internal one to the external location, towards the end, if it's not already there

    NSString *localPath    = [self localPathForPlist:@"data" internal:FALSE];
    NSString *internalPath = [self localPathForPlist:@"data" internal:TRUE];

    NSLog( @"local path=%@", localPath );

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    BOOL localPlistExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:localPath];

    // the first time you run this, it'll do one, then the other for all other runs:
    if( localPlistExists ) NSLog( @"local plist exists" );
    else                   NSLog( @"local plist does NOT exist" );

    NSLog( @"key1's value from internal=%@", [self readFromPlist:@"key1" internal:TRUE ] );
    NSLog( @"key1's value from external=%@", [self readFromPlist:@"key1" internal:FALSE] );

    NSLog( @"setting internal key1 to new-value1" );
    [self writeToPlist:@"key1" setValue:@"new-value1" internal:TRUE ];

    NSLog( @"setting external key1 to new-value1" );
    [self writeToPlist:@"key1" setValue:@"new-value1" internal:FALSE];

    NSLog( @"key1's value from internal=%@", [self readFromPlist:@"key1" internal:TRUE ] );
    NSLog( @"key1's value from external=%@", [self readFromPlist:@"key1" internal:FALSE] );

    // the first time you run this, it'll do one, then the other for all other runs:
    if( localPlistExists ) NSLog( @"since local plist exists, leaving alone" );
    else
    {
        NSLog( @"since local plist does NOT exist, cloning from internal copy");
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:internalPath toPath:localPath error:nil];
    }

    NSLog( @"key1's value from internal=%@", [self readFromPlist:@"key1" internal:TRUE ] );
    NSLog( @"key1's value from external=%@", [self readFromPlist:@"key1" internal:FALSE] );

    NSLog( @"setting internal key1 to new-value1" );
    [self writeToPlist:@"key1" setValue:@"new-value1" internal:TRUE ];

    NSLog( @"setting external key1 to new-value1" );
    [self writeToPlist:@"key1" setValue:@"new-value1" internal:FALSE];

    NSLog( @"key1's value from internal=%@", [self readFromPlist:@"key1" internal:TRUE ] );
    NSLog( @"key1's value from external=%@", [self readFromPlist:@"key1" internal:FALSE] );

    // notice that from one run to another, changes to the internal one don't "carry over", because it's read-only
    // but ones in the external one do
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Example screenshot for the first time you run it: [image: First Execution]

Example screenshot for successive runs: [image: Later Executions]